# Аналог API FaceMatica

Tags: api

Всем привет.
Сейчас использеутся https://api.facematica.vocord.ru/v1/#01-post-face-detect
Необходимо заменить API в сзязи с его блокировкой.
Интересует метод `/detect` для сравнения лиц, где в response один из параметров совпадение  в %, можно планное API. 
Подскажите пожалуйста не русский аналог.
Всем добра)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто оставлю это здесь.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html

`composer require aws/aws-sdk-php`

AWS Rekognition to Compare Face in PHP

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Infrastructure;

use Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient;

class MyComparator
{

/**Credentials for access AWS Service code parameter*/   

$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('{AWS access key ID}', 
'{AWS secret access key}');


/**Get Rekognition Access*/

$rekognitionClient = RekognitionClient::factory(array(
'region' => "us-east-1",
'version' => 'latest',
'credentials' => $credentials
));


/**Calling Compare Face function*/

$compareFaceResults= $rekognitionClient->compareFaces([
    'SimilarityThreshold' => 1,
    'SourceImage' => [
        'Bytes' => file_get_contents("SourceImage.jpg")
    ],
    'TargetImage' => [
        'Bytes' => file_get_contents("TargetImage.jpg")
    ],
]);


/**Response to JSON Data*/

$FaceMatchesResult = $compareFaceResults['FaceMatches'];
$SimilarityResult = $FaceMatchesResult['Similarity'] //Here You will get similarity
$sourceImageFace = $compareFaceResults['SourceImageFace']
$sourceConfidence = $sourceImageFace['Confidence'] // //Here You will get confidence of the picture
```